# " No converter found for return value of type: class java.lang.Integer" in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My spring MVC can't return Integer or Object to page, only String can return to page,i can use PrinterWriter print a Integer to page but can't return Integer
Code:

```
        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value = "/Integer.action", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
        public Integer testInteger(){
            return 1;
        }
```

Error:

```
No converter found for return value of type: class java.lang.Integer
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.lang.Integer
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:233)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

It's not problem with shiro, i have this problem before i use shiro.

HelloWeb-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- freemarker config -->
    <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/templates/"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rtx" />

</beans>
```

Web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

spring-web-shiro.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

    <description>Shiro Configuration</description>

    <bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="realm" ref="myShiroRealm" />
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myShiroRealm" class="com.rtx.shiro.LoginRealm">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Shiro Filter -->
    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
        <property name="successUrl" value="/user_page.php" />
        <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/404.php" />
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
                /login.php =anon
                /doLogin.action = anon
                /** = authc
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager" />

    <bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"
          depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

my springMvc can only return string to page, can't return object or integer, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-responsebody), when you annotate with `@ResponseBody`, Spring will use an `HttpMessageConverter`.

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#rest-message-conversion) for list of built-in converters. The default list of enabled converters include (from [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L781)):

- `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`, converts `byte[]` to `application/octet-stream`
- `StringHttpMessageConverter`, converts `String` to `text/plain`
- `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`, converts `Resource` to dynamic media type
- `ResourceRegionHttpMessageConverter`, converts `ResourceRegion` to dynamic media type
- `SourceHttpMessageConverter`, converts `Source` to `application/xml`, `text/xml`, or `application/*+xml`
- `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter`, converts various types to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`, converts `@XmlRootElement` annotated object to `application/xml`, `text/xml`, or `application/*+xml`
- *more*<sup>1</sup>

As you can see, none of them supports conversion of an `Integer` object.

Simplest way to solve the problem is to change return type to `String`, and calling `toString()` on your `Integer` object.

Alternatively, add a custom message converter, as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-message-converters).

---

<sup>1</sup> There might be more enabled converters, depending on which Spring modules are installed, e.g. if Jackson is present, you'll get JSON support:

- `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, converts `ObjectMapper` supported object to `application/json`
- `AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter`, converts `Feed` to `application/atom+xml`
- `RssChannelHttpMessageConverter`, converts `Channel` to `application/rss+xml`
- `MappingJackson2SmileHttpMessageConverter`, converts `ObjectMapper` supported object to `application/x-jackson-smile`
- `MappingJackson2CborHttpMessageConverter`, converts `ObjectMapper` supported object to `application/cbor`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `Integer` you can return `ResponseEntity` and wrap your data into it.

Something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Integer.action", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<?> testInteger(){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(5);
    // return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(5, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Edit 1:

As suggested you can convert Integer to string

```
 @ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/Integer.action", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public String testInteger(){
    Integer a = 1;
    return a.toString();
}
```

Comment: `ResponseEntity` only supports the same object types as the return types of a `@ResponseBody` annotated method, since both ways use the same list of `HttpMessageConverter` implementations to do the conversion to an HTTP response body. --- Also, `ResponseEntity` is an alternative to `@ResponseBody`, so don't use both. --- As the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-responseentity) says: *`ResponseEntity` is like `@ResponseBody` but with status and headers*.